# Use moshi with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, moshi

How do i use Moshi with Spring boot i have set the json mapper and added the pom but i don't seems to work

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=moshi

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>moshi</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>moshi-adapters</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: only jackson and gson are supported out-of-the-box. For others you need to do additional configuration and write additinal infrastructure classes.